# upgrade from TFS 2008 to 2010 - cannot connect to Share Point documents

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have upgraded my TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 to a different machine. I tried to follow the instructions, and everything works but the SharePoint documents.
I had TFS 2008 with WSS 2.0 on Server 2003.
The new machine is Server 2008 R2 with TFS 2010 and WSS 3.0.

I restored the content DB to the new server's database.
I tried upgrading the content DB (STS_Content_TFS) with ***stsadm -o addcontentdb*** but failed with the following message:

> The pre-upgrade scan tool has not yet been run on this database SPContentDatabase Name=STS_Content_TFS Parent=SPDatabaseServiceInstance. You must run the pre-upgrade scan tool before you can continue with the upgrade process. Run the tool from the following path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\bin\prescan.exe.

***prescan.exe*** doesn't run and ***stsadm -o preupgradecheck*** doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.
Documentation is very confusing.
Here are the steps I took:

1. Prescan on the wss 2.0 machine (and not on the new wss 3 machine)
2. Backup the content DB
3. restore the DB on new machine
4. stsadm -o addcontentdb
5. manually install TFS SharePoint extensions. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/01/13/how-to-manually-install-tfs-extensions-for-sharepoint.aspx
6. SharePoint admin: deploy solutions
7. TFS admin - grant access
8. TFS admin setup sharepoint

This is in short, of course